# Copiar arquivos mostrando progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia.

Tenho um pequeno código onde copio arquivos de uma pasta para outra, mas como alguns arquivos demoram, gostaria de mostra uma barra de progresso, como posso fazer isso com este seguinte código:

```
        string ArquivoOrigem = System.IO.Path.Combine(CaminhoOrigem, NomeArquivo);
        string ArquivoDestino = System.IO.Path.Combine(CaminhoDestino, NomeArquivo);

        File.Copy(Path.Combine(CaminhoOrigem, ArquivoOrigem), Path.Combine(CaminhoDestino, ArquivoDestino), true);

        System.IO.File.Copy(ArquivoOrigem, ArquivoDestino, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim:

`FileSystem.CopyFile(ArquivoOrigem, ArquivoDestino, UIOption.AllDialogs);`

Comment: Não consegui fazer desta forma, teria mais algo que deve ser implementado?

Comment: Aparentemente não, qual retorno ou erro está recebendo?

Comment: Aparece os seguintes erros.  Error 1 The name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the current context /   Error 2 The name 'UIOption' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Adiciona referência a: `Microsoft.VisualBasic` 
e  no código: `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`